# Changing css on span click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a 3 spans I use to navigate to 3 different pages, they basically act like buttons for me, only a plugin I use require them to be spans (why I cant use buttons, so dont tell me to use buttons instead).

What I want to do is change background color on the clicked span, so if I am on page 3, span 3 is green for instance, and when I click on another span, that one changes and the previous green span goes back to normal.

Any idea on how to do this either in js,html or css?

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here and [describe what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if posting the code would help too much, its basically 3 spans in a div, with some standard css code to them. What I've tried is giving them different ID's and then adding onClick to each span that sets the background color to green on the one I click, which didnt work for some reason.

Comment: Most importantly, tell us something about the mysterious plugin that requires a span for a button.

Comment: And is it a jquery plugin? Then add jquery to your tags and look at .on("click",function()..

Comment: @Jacco Think about how we'd debug this -- it'd be a lot easier with a jsfiddle or example code, rather than trying to guess what your page looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily achieved with jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
$('span').on('click', function() {
   $('span').removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

**CSS**

```
span {
   background: #c1c1c1;
   display: block;
   width: 100px;
   height: 25px;
   float: left;
}

span.active {
   background: green;
}
```

**html**

```
<span class="active">one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
```

This just adds the class `active` to the clicked element while removing any `active` before.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/m8TLb/1/)